# Flow + Redux: Error with redux default actions and strongly typed actions

Tags: reactjs, redux, flowtype

I am attempting to use flow disjoint unions to strongly type redux action objects, as suggested in the Flow docs (https://flow.org/en/docs/frameworks/redux/), but am now running into issues with flow throwing an error handling default redux actions (`@@redux/INIT`, `@@redux/PROBE_UNKNOWN_ACTION`, etc.).

A sample of this code would be:

```
// Constant action type strings
export const INIT_STORIES: 'INIT_STORIES' = 'INIT_STORIES';
export const UPDATE_STORY: 'UPDATE_STORY' = 'UPDATE_STORY';

// Strongly typed action objects
export type InitAction = {
  type: typeof INIT_STORIES, stories: Array<Story>
};
export type UpdateAction = {
  type: typeof UPDATE_STORY, storyIndex: number, story: Story
};

// Disjoint union wrapper
export type ActionType = 
| InitAction
| UpdateAction;

//reducer
export default function storiesReducer(
  stories: Array<Story> = [],
  action: ActionType
): Array<Story> {
  // Error is thrown at function invocation, prior to the first inner line of function
  // Uncaught TypeError: [tcomb] Invalid value {"type": "@@redux/INIT"
  console.log(action);
  ...
}
```

I have only been able to find 1 issue/solution online for this problem, and it uses the more complex flow-runtime to solve the the problem. 
(https://github.com/codemix/flow-runtime/issues/80)

I feel like as the recommended syntax for integrating Redux with Flow, there should be a more simplistic solution than? I have tried making the type of the function parameter `action` a disjoint union with a object with an undefined string type (i.e `{ type: string }`) but that throws a type error with static linting/typing inside the reducer because it cannot be sure what branch of the disjoint union object the `action` object is.

Comment: Are you using the libdef provided in flow-typed?

Comment: @LewisChung No I'm not, I wasn't aware that there are ready-made libraries for this. I will definitely look into this. I would imagine I can apply my action definitions as disjoint unions ontop of the base redux action types in the `flow-typed` libdef?

Comment: Since you're using tcomb, it looks like you'll still run into the same issue. I asked if you used flow-typed because it looks like it's possible to modify the flow-typed definition that exists here: https://github.com/flowtype/flow-typed/blob/master/definitions/npm/redux_v3.x.x/flow_v0.33.x-/redux_v3.x.x.js to automatically account for the default flow actions so you don't get the {"type": "@@redux/INIT"}. That being said, I'm not quite sure how tcomb actually uses libdefs from flow-typed.

Comment: The `$Subtype<string>` typing prevents the errors from showing up and still allows the flow runtime to read the appropriate branch in the switch/case, so I think its a good enough solution! Thanks for the pointer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest solution, without importing the full `flow-typed` package for redux, is to add a disjoint union `{ type: $Subtype<string> }` to the `ActionType` disjoint union type, as below:

```
// Disjoint union wrapper
export type ActionType = 
| InitAction
| UpdateAction
| { type: $Subtype<string> };


//reducer
export default function storiesReducer(
  stories: Array<Story> = [],
  action: ActionType
): Array<Story> {
  console.log(action);
  ...
}
```

While this will not throw an appropriate error if the action type string was entered wrong, since it allows all string types, it will allow appropriate branching to recognize different object shapes inside the switch/case block.